# How to get the recordcount of JSON results returned from Coldfusion Component?

Tags: json, coldfusion

I have a Coldfusion Component which returns my search results from a query in JSON using serializeJSON(myquery).

The results returned dont have the ROWCOUNT before the COLUMNS, if i do return the results with the ROWCOUNT then it messes everything up.

What is the best way to display the recordcount without using the ROWCOUNT value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there is something you are not telling us, you do not need to include an extra row count. It can be derived from the result.

By default `serializeJSON(queryObject)` returns a structure with two keys: `DATA` and `COLUMNS` (both arrays). `DATA` represents the rows in the query. So to obtain the query row count, simply check the length of the `DATA` array.

Comment: Welcome. I was going to delete my answer, since it essentially says same the same thing as Tony's (and he beat me by under a minute ;-) but .. decided to leave it as a good description of the anatomy of the serialized query object - and up vote his answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

If the serialized object is a query object, you should be able to deserialize the JSON and get the array length of records from the result structure's `data` key.

So,

`arrayLen(deserializeJSON(result).data)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony, I will try out that method as well

Comment: It essentially does what Leigh explained in his answer. We apparently were typing out answers at the same time ;)

Comment: All I did was add this to my Ajax call: res.DATA.length and appended it to a container and it worked. Regarding your answer, would that go in the Ajax call as well? Forgive me if my question sounds a bit stupid, my query skills are non existent!!

Comment: @johnnyc0506 Tony's code is all cfml. The code illustrates that the data value of the json object is an array with a length that represents the count of rows in the query object. It wasn't clear in your question that you were using the results inside the browser.

Comment: Exactly :) Beat me to it. Either method would suffice when passing into a ajax call. My example would have to be evaluated in a `.cfm` page. I'd personally just use `res.DATA.length` as it's more direct to the JavaScript code unless you will be using the JSON results in the CFML side passed that point.